# Insert concat of two columns back into one of the original columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL-Server.

I have a table AVQ. Two of the columns are named Questions and Instructions. I would like to concatenate those two columns and store the result back into Questions.

I've got the concat query `SELECT question + ISNULL(' ' + instructions, '') from AVQ;`

But I'm unsure of how to get the result back into the Questions column.

I've tried to use that query as a subquery like so:

```
update AVQ
set Question = (SELECT question + ISNULL(' ' + instructions, '') from AVQ)
where AVID = 2;
```

but I get the error `Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

Could someone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: if you're using sql 2012+ `CONCAT` will ignore nulls `set Question = CONCAT(Question, ' ' + instructions)`

Comment: The subquery is returning more than 1 row, hence SQL Server is giving you this error, as @vkp said below, there is no need of subquery for this, you can just use the direct update statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sub-query isn't required here.

```
update AVQ
set Question = question + ISNULL(' ' + instructions, '')
where AVID = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is a method that might actually be more efficient:

```
update AVG
    set Question = Question + ' ' + instructions
    where AVID = 2 and instructions is not null;
```

Why bother even attempting to do the update if `instructions` is empty?

Answer (score 0):

you could use a case statement to update all of them at once... or add a where to do 1 at a time...

```
Update AVQ
set question = case when instructions is null then question 
                    else Question + ' ' + instructions end
where AVID =2
```

I didn't want to leave an extra ' ' at the end if instructions were null, so I used a case statement.